# Is something wrong in this proof?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

Show that if $\sum a_nx^n$ has convergence radio $R$ and $\limsup |a_n| > 0 $, then $R\leq 1$.

Proof:

Suppose that $\sum a_nx^n$ has convergence radio $R$ and $\limsup |a_n|=\alpha > 0$. Suppose by contradiction that $R> 1$, then exists $x_0$ such that $1<x_0<R$ and $\sum a_n x^n_0$ converge, i.e:
$$\limsup \sqrt[n]{|a_n|x^n_0} \leq 1$$
$$\limsup \sqrt[n]{|a_n|} \limsup|x_0| \leq 1 $$
$$\limsup \sqrt[n]{|\alpha|}x_0 \leq 1$$ 
$$ x_0\leq 1 $$

But this is a contradiction. Therefore $R\leq 1$.

Is something wrong in this proof?

Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Well, you need to be a bit more explicit relating convergence and absolute convergence when you transitions from $a_nx_0^n$ to $|a_n|x_0^n$.

Comment: Also why does $\limsup \sqrt[n]{|\alpha|}x_0 \leq 1 \Rightarrow x_0 \leq 1$?

Comment: Yes, thank you both :). On the other hand, the idea of the proof is correct, right?

Comment: As far as i can see it's correct. However it's talking about convergence ratio $R$, but what is your center? Otherwise the ratio makes no sense. Also the comment I made about the implication. You only explicitly said that $\limsup |a_n|=\alpha > 0$. Suppose $\alpha=25$, then what is the limsup?

Comment: Well, actually this was an exercise and response in a test. It said nothing about the center. Now, do you mean $\limsup\sqrt[n]{|25|}$=1?